# git bash terminal increase number of lines to see (windows)

Tags: windows, git-bash

I'm using a windows os. For working with git we use git bash.
I would like to increase the number of output lines that I can see in the history of this terminal.
At the moment it is probably by something like 1000 but I would like to increase it to at least 10.000

Comment: Looks like it uses the normal Windows console. If you right-click the title bar, there should be an option to change the default settings, including the window buffer height.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using the latest [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/) (like [`PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe), that you can extract wherever you want), you can call C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit\git-bash.exe.

That open a bash Windows session from which you can (with a right-click) select "Options":

[image: options]

You can change the "scrollback lines" there.

If you are using a regular CMD session, see "[More lines in command window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653487/6309)".