# Why does this nested loop output starts at 8 and 18?

Tags: c#, console-application

I don't understand why this loop starts at 8 and 18 when I output it, but when I try "i < 10 and j < 10", it starts at 2 and 2. Can someone explain this to me?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < 100; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i = {0} and j = {1}", i, j);
            }                 
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot of my issue:**
[image]

Comment: These loops "start at" 2 and 2.  It's not clear what problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: I don't observe the same behaviour with this code, running it starts the loops at 2 and 2

Comment: [I can't reproduce this...](http://rextester.com/YIXJ17802)

Comment: Can you clarify your question of 'when i output it': if you have a second, unworking version of the code, please share it?

Comment: I also [could not replicate this issue](https://repl.it/repls/ThornyHummingDistributionsoftware).

Comment: For those who can't reproduce it, I'm using Visual Studio, and my console output starts at 8 and 18 when using < 100. I still can't understand why.

Comment: @Voidsower: I'm also using Visual Studio, copied and pasted the exact code from this question, and when I step through in my debugger the very first line of output shows the values 2 and 2.  You must be doing something else wrong.  Loops are not broken in C#.  These values start at 2 exactly as you've defined them.

Comment: Maybe check with someone and try to answer his question - `How many fingers am I holding up?` :)

Comment: @RandRandom Before trying to act smart, I can send you a screen shot with the output. For some reason my console output is hiding the results.

Comment: @Voidsower Please post the screenshot with the output in your question

Comment: Didnt try to act smart, thought it was funny sorry if it offended you. Yes, pls provide a screenshot than I can see the scrollbar thats hiding your output. (yes, now I acted smart)

Comment: No chance the window just doesnt scroll back that far?

Comment: Maybe that can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740876/more-lines-in-command-window - you can also try to redirect the console output to file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script

Comment: @RandRandom Just added a Screenshot, also showing to code for you to see that I'm not kidding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that it isn't starting at `i = 2` and `j = 2`?  You are running this loop so many times that your console output may not show that it starts at 2,2, even though it does.  Try setting a breakpoint in the second for loop, I think you'll see it is starting at 2, 2. That's because the buffer size is too small.

Here's what you can do:

- Run your project.
- Right-click on the title bar-> Properties-> Layout.
- Set your height to something really large.

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160977/is-there-a-limit-on-the-output-of-console-window) for more.

Comment: While I think you might be correct about the source of their confusion, this should probably be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I do not have the reputation to comment.

Comment: You are right, if I set a break point, it shows 2 and 2. Any idea why is this happening? I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio community. Is it normal or just a bug? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The buffer size is too small.  Run your project.  Right click on the title bar->Properties->Layout.  Set your height to something really large.  This may help.  (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160977/is-there-a-limit-on-the-output-of-console-window)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you exceed the number of lines that your console is set to display at once.

The property is called `Console.BufferHeight`.

Try writing `Console.WriteLine(Console.BufferHeight);` to see the number of lines your console is set to display at once.

You can change it simply by writing setting it to your desired value, e.g. `Console.BufferHeight = 20000;` or changing the settings of the console by accessing the properties in the manner, that @Greg elaborated on.