# Breaking out of Infinite C++ loop in codeblock

Tags: loops, codeblocks

I am running a program written in C++ in Codeblocks in Windows. The major part of the program is structured like this:

```
while(true){
    // do and print something
    if (<something happens>)
        break;
    // do something
}
```

The problem is it takes a long time for the program to run in the windows cmd (which opens when I press the "build and run" option in Codeblocks). I would like to "stop" the output on the window and see the stuff that has been printed so far. How can I do the same? (If I press `Ctrl + C`, then it simply exits the window.)

Comment: Pause? (9 more to go)

Comment: (assuming your keyboard has that button)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With adding to pressing the pause button to stop command prompt, you could also extend the amount of viewable lines for future use.

[More lines in command window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740876/more-lines-in-command-window)